# efficiently get URL from Chrome v47+

Tags: c#, google-chrome, url

I need to get the URL from the active tab from chrome (v47.0.2526.106 m (64-bit)).
I have a method that does work greatly for Firefox / IE, but my method for Chrome is VERY slow and 60% of the time will crash chrome :

```
public static string GetURL(Process process, string programName, out string url)
{
    string temp = null;
    if (programName.Equals("chrome"))
    {
        AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
        if (element != null)
        {
            AutomationElement edit = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree,
            new AndCondition(
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "address and search bar", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit)));

            temp = ((ValuePattern)edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value as string;
        }
    }
    url = temp;
    return url;
}
```

So, to my question:
**Is there another way to do this efficiently?**

Comment: _"I need to get the URL from the active tab"_ - sounds like an XY problem. Can't you use FiddlerCore instead?

Comment: I don't understand how this is an XY problem, I need to get the URL and this code although it works, is very unstable, so I'm searching for another way to do it. As for FiddlerCore I have no idea what it is, could you please give an example of how to use it ? Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you need to get the URL from the active tab?

Comment: I need the active URL to check which site the user is on. Depending on the site, the program acts differently.